# How to apply filter conditions gradually without breaking the previous filtering conditions

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Maybe this question seems stupid but I need to learn how it is possible to fix it.
In Laravel, I try to apply many conditions according to users choices, like this:

```
$query = Model::query();
if ($request->has('ids')) {
    $query = $query->whereIn('id', $request->get('ids'));
}
if ( ($request->has('fruits')) ) {
    $query = $query->whereHas('fruits', function ($sQuery) use ($list) {
       $sQuery->whereIn('fruit.id', $list);
    });
}
if ($request->has('date')) {
   $query = $query->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $request->get('date'))
              ->orWhereDate('updated_at', '>=', $request->get('date'));
}
```

The fact is the conditions about dates break previous filter conditions. I am getting other raws which do not match to first conditions. I guess it is because orWhereDate which is applied as condition "or" about all others. How to deal with this?

Comment: One small thing to mention, there is no need to redeclare the `$query` variable like `$query = $query->where(...)`.  You can just modify it `$query->where(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. I prefer answer my own question than delete it.

```
$query = Model::query();
if ($request->has('ids')) {
    $query = $query->whereIn('id', $request->get('ids'));
}
if ( ($request->has('fruits')) ) {
    $query = $query->whereHas('fruits', function ($sQuery) use ($list) {
       $sQuery->whereIn('fruit.id', $list);
    });
}
if ($request->has('date')) {
   $date = $request->get('date');
   $query->where(function($query) use ($date){
           $query->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $date)
              ->orWhereDate('updated_at', '>=', $date);
   });
}
```

Hope this could help quickly someone.

Comment: I recommend you to drop the use of `if` everywhere (for eloquent) and start using [`when`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses)

Comment: Interesting @matiaslauriti . I did not know it, thanks